# Group Array values for SwiftUI Chart

Tags: swift, swiftui

I am trying to create a pie chart using the following example

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/charts/visualizing_your_app_s_data

I have successfully displayed data from an array by doing

```
    Chart(store.profile!.invoices) { expense in
        SectorMark(
            angle: .value("Expense", expense.total),
            innerRadius: .ratio(0.618),
            angularInset: 1.5
        )
        .cornerRadius(5)
        .foregroundStyle(by: .value("Expense", expense.category.rawValue))
        .annotation(position: .overlay) {
            Text("\(expense.total)")
                .font(.headline)
                .foregroundStyle(.white)
        }
    }
    .chartLegend(alignment: .center, spacing: 18)
    .chartAngleSelection($selectedAngel)
    .scaledToFit()
    #if os(macOS)
    .transaction {
        $0.animation = nil // Do not animate on MacOS.
    }
    #endif
```

However this creates a `SectorMark` for each invoice in `store.profile!.invoices`, how can I group the values by using the `Invoice.category` ?

The Invoice object has category enum which we use to store as Invoice.category

```
enum Category: String, Codable {

    static let allValues = [Bills, Food, Maintenance, Entertainment,  Other]

    case Bills = "Bills"
    case Food = "Food"
    case Maintenance = "Maintenance"
    case Entertainment = "Entertainment"
    case Other = "Other"
}
```

Comment: You need to fix your data source, use a loop or high order function where you sum the amount of the invoices per category and then use that collection as your data source for the chart instead.

Comment: `Dictionary(grouping:)`

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on the answer above, I sum up the amount per category and use that collection

```
// Step 1: Create object to story data
struct CategoryData: Identifiable {
    let id = UUID()
    let category: String
    let totalAmount: Int
}

// Step 2: Create a new collection with CategoryData instances
@State var categoryData: [CategoryData] = []


// Step 3: Loop through data to sort onAppear

  for invoice in store.profile!.invoices {
      let category = invoice.label.rawValue
      totalAmountsByCategory[category, default: 0] += invoice.total
  }
        
  categoryData = totalAmountsByCategory.map { category, totalAmount in
            return CategoryData(category: category, totalAmount: totalAmount)
  }
```